# Mopidy not in mac with python

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, gstreamer

I cannot get mopidy to work with mac osx Yosemite and python 2.7. I installed gstreamer and installed everything modipy needs but I get this Traceback in the terminal when I try to run modipy:

```
(oldpy) Connors-MacBook-Pro:~ connor$ mopidy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/connor/anaconda3/envs/oldpy/bin/mopidy", line 7, in <module>
    from mopidy.__main__ import main
  File "/Users/connor/anaconda3/envs/oldpy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mopidy/__main__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from mopidy.internal.gi import Gst  # noqa: F401
  File "/Users/connor/anaconda3/envs/oldpy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mopidy/internal/gi.py", line 9, in <module>
    gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'require_version'
(oldpy) Connors-MacBook-Pro:~ connor$
```

here is the homebrew error i get when i try to install modipy with homebrew:

```
(oldpy) Connors-MacBook-Pro:~ connor$ brew install mopidy
==> Installing mopidy from mopidy/mopidy
==> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/76/427ad1fbe879034e34
Already downloaded: /Users/connorwoodford/Library/Caches/Homebrew/mopidy-2.1.0.tar.gz
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/usr/local/Cel
Warning: Calling <<-EOS.undent is deprecated!
Use <<~EOS instead.
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/mopidy/homebrew-mopidy/mopidy.rb:72:in `plist'
Please report this to the mopidy/mopidy tap!
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing `python-gi`. Please try `brew install pygobject3 --with-python3 gtk+3` and then run `mopidy` again

Comment: Still not working. I did have to install with pip because homebrew gave me this error: Warning: Calling <<-EOS.undent is deprecated!

Comment: It looks like you need to run `brew update` before running the previous command again.

Comment: Just ran the update and I am still getting the same error with homebrew.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the error you are getting so that maybe someone else who knows it a little better could help?

Comment: Ok here is the updated code.

Comment: "Please report this to the mopidy/mopidy tap!" Did you report it?

Comment: no but i think i will.